# foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given", exception: "ErrorException

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I am trying to use data tables in laravel but getting below response:

```
{
    "message": "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
```

I have tried this code in my controller:

```
$dataLists= DB::table("table_name")
                ->select('column_1', 'column_2')
                ->get();
return Datatables::of($dataLists)
            ->make(true);
```

If I print $datalists it display data in below formate

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [column_1] => 386932
                    [column_2] => data name 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [column_1] => 8764358
                    [column_2] => data name 2
                )
        )
)
```

My php version is: 8.0.0
and laravel version is: 8.20.1

Can someone please help me to find out Where I am wrong?

Comment: where is your using foreach?

Comment: @KamleshPaul I am not using foreach anywhere in my code it might be in in datatable own classes.

Comment: it can't be possible please debug your application

Comment: don't use get() while passing to the datatables

Answer (score 4):

just clear config cache of laravel 
`php artisan config:cache`